# to many IF how to make quicker search c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

Have 5 Names and 5 number.
Giv name need number.
better way?

```
 string name = "Mark";
    int x;
if(name == "John")
{
 x = 1;
}else if(name == "Jimy"){
x = 2;
}else if(name == "Mark"){
x = 3;
}.... etc
return x;
```

result is x=3.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have unique names? That doesn't seem like a very sustainable `key`

Comment: Always 5 same names and number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often if you have a unique list of items that you want to associate with some other item, a `Dictionary` is a good solution. Each item in a dictionary is called a `KeyValuePair`, and consists of two parts: a unique `key`, which in this case would be the name, and a `value` associated with that key, which in this case is an int.

For your example, it would look something like:

```
// The part in parenthesis specifies that the keys will be 
// case-insensitive when doing comparisons, so you can search 
// for "john", "John", or "JOHN", and get the same value back
private static  Dictionary<string, int> nameValues = 
    new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"John", 1},
    {"Jimmy", 2},
    {"Mark", 3}
};
```

And a method for retrieving the int value for a name might look like:

```
private static int GetIntForName(string name)
{
    var valueIfNotFound = -1;
    return nameValues.ContainsKey(name) ? nameValues[name] : valueIfNotFound;
}
```